# Using the Keyboard.IsKeyDown in a loop C# form app

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to make a platformer game in windows c# forms, in my main game loop I've got some pieces of code but I can't seem to get the user input to work correctly, any help would be appreciated!

this is my code:

```
while (true)// this is still in testing so it should go on forver
if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.Insert) == true)
{
btn1.Left = btn1.Left + 1;// btn is a button
Update();
}
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50);
}
```

whenever I run this the program becomes unresponding and eventually crashes
and when I press insert or any other key I used it does not work

Comment: Are you doing your update in background?

Comment: it's obviously unresponding, because it's always "busy" running your loop and sleeping....

Comment: I dont understand the question, can you elaborate about what is "background" @MarkBenovsky

Comment: so why do when i press insert for a long time nothing happenes? @René Vogt

Comment: You should rather subscribe to a `KeyDown` event of your form or the appropriate control. If you subscribe to the form's `KeyDown` event, remeber to set the form's `KeyPreview` property to true.

Comment: You're calling `Thread.Sleep()` in an infinite loop on the UI thread.

Comment: You have your loop in main application's thread, as it is forever, it cannot stop and perform other tasks, you need to run it in another thread.

Comment: I wouldn't use winforms to make a platformer game....this is entirely the wrong framework

Comment: so just to get things straight, when I use the Keyboard.IsKeyDown isn't actually checking if a key is down? I am avoiding multiple threads because I want to be able to debug it without multi-thread debugging @RenéVogt

Comment: The `Keyboard` class is actually part of WPF, you should not mix that with Windows Forms.

Comment: I don't intend to be rude, but your question, your comments and your answers to other's comments show you lack knowledge of how forms, events, threads and responsiveness works, which  makes me think you're **far** from being able to program any kind of game, let alone a platformer. If you're learning to program, a game is not the right way to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this code is running in a `Form` you should subscribe to the `Form`'s [`KeyDown`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keydown(v=vs.110).aspx) event:

```
public partial class YourForm : Form
{
    public YourForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        KeyDown += KeyDownHandler; // subscribe to event
        KeyPreview = true; // set to true so key events of child controls are caught too
    }

    private void KeyDownHandler(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode != Keys.Insert) return;
        btn1.Left = btn1.Left + 1;// btn is a button
        e.Handled = true; // indicate that the key was handled by you
        //Update(); // this is not necessary, after this method is finished, the UI will be updated
    }
}
```

So the `KeyDownHandler` gets called if the user presses the key. There is no need to pull the keyboard state in a loop that blocks your UI thread.

---

The subscription to the event and the `KeyPreview` value can be set in the designer window too if you prefer that to writing in your own code.

---

And btw: the `Keyboard` class is part of WPF. You should not mix that with Windows Forms.

Comment: is there a way to execute a line of code only if *any* key was pressed no by using event handler, but by using if an if statement like in console application where you have the command Console.ReadKey(true);?

Comment: Where you want to do that? If you _wait_ for a key that way you will always block your UI.